# need clarity between stage/scene and screen

Tags: javafx

The following elementary code works perfectly. It determines the list of available screens, and then identifies the largest one, and then sets the size of the stage equal to the dimensions of the largest monitor.

```
public class MaximizedStage extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ObservableList<Screen> monitors = Screen.getScreens();
    //determine the larger monitor
    Rectangle2D bounds = monitors.get(0).getVisualBounds();     //get the bounds of the default monitor
    int preferred_mon = 0;
    var x = bounds.getMinX();
    var y = bounds.getMinY();
    var w = bounds.getWidth();
    var h = bounds.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Count of monitors : "+monitors.size()+" default monitor size : w: "+w+" h: "+h);
    for (int mon = 1; mon < monitors.size(); mon++) {           // for each of the other monitors
        Rectangle2D next_monitor_bounds = monitors.get(mon).getVisualBounds();  //get the size
        if ((next_monitor_bounds.getHeight() > h) && (next_monitor_bounds.getWidth() > w)) {
            //larger monitor, update parameters
            preferred_mon = mon;
            x = next_monitor_bounds.getMinX();
            y = next_monitor_bounds.getMinY();
            w = next_monitor_bounds.getWidth();
            h = next_monitor_bounds.getHeight();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest monitor : index: "+preferred_mon+" w: "+w+" h: "+h);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group()));
    stage.setTitle("Full screen");

    // Set the position and size of the stage equal to the position and
    // size of the screen

    stage.setX(x);
    stage.setY(y);
    stage.setWidth(w);
    stage.setHeight(h);

    // Show the stage       
    stage.show();
}
}
```

My question is: where in this code does the stage (or the Scene) know which is the final selection among the screens to display on? Am struggling to understand the linkage between stage/scene and the choice of the monitor. The final objective is to prepare multiple different stages, run each one on a different thread, and direct their output to a different monitor.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The biggest screen is saved in the preferred_mon variable. It is updated whenever the new screen size is bigger than the screens checked before. 
(directly below the (//larger monitor (...)" commentary.

Comment: For your additional question: You don't need the check for the biggest monitor, just iterate over all monitors and display your scene accordingly on each monitor.

Comment: @Dugnom I understand that. But how do I tell a stage to go to a specific screen ? Does it do by just matching the size ? Is that the hidden logic ? Could I for example, say that show stage s ONLY on screen 2 ? Tks

Comment: You are not choosing the monitor, you are choosing the coordinates to be in the corner of the monitor and using the width and height to set the opposite corner

Comment: Note that the UI is single-threaded. So, you can't have separate UI threads without running separate instances of the application. Just because you have different windows on different monitors (screens) doesn't mean you have different UI threads.

Comment: The `Screen` bounds give, as well as the width and height of the screen, the location of that screen in a virtual coordinate space. This defines the arrangement of the different display devices, so, for example, it defines what happens when a user drags a window from one device to another. This is determined by user settings at the OS level. Since the x and y coordinates of the stage are set to the x and y coordinates of the chosen screen, the stage appears in that screen.

Comment: @James_D ... understood - so the monitors are actually cascading as a continuous X Y values, and the physical displays handle their respective starting co-ordinates and ending co-ordinates - I verified your statement using a middle of the screen X location and that clarified everything... Thanks ..

Comment: @mrmcwolf .. I see... so, no advantage creating multiple independent threads each handling a different stage/ its own monitor. Tks for the clarification.. Helps

Comment: Not just "no advantage", but active _disadvantages_. JavaFX is single-threaded. Accessing/modifying state connected to the scene graph displayed on the screen on any thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread (i.e., the "UI thread") is _broken code_.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to set the stage to [full screen](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen(boolean)), rather than adjust it’s size? Even if you do decide to adjust the size, wouldn’t be better to set [maximized](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaximized(boolean)) instead?

Comment: You may benefit from reading the [Application](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) javadoc to learn about the application lifecycle and threading rules.

Comment: Converted comment to an answer (not addressing the threading issues as these are vague in the question anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bounds of each screen are relative to some virtual coordinate system. The bounds describe the width and height of each screen, but also the position of the screen in that coordinate system, thereby defining the locations of the different display devices relative to each other. Typically these are defined by user preferences set at the OS level.

On the set up I'm currently using, I have a MacBook Pro connected to an external display (which is configured as the primary display). In System Preferences, this looks like:

[image]

which is a decent approximation to the physical layout I have. This means I can drag windows from the main screen (the one shown on the right) to the left edge of that screen, and then onto the laptop screen (shown on the left).

The larger screen has dimensions 3008x1692, and the laptop screen has dimensions 1680x1050. The bounds are reported as

```
Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=3008.0, maxY=1692.0, width=3008.0, height=1692.0]
Rectangle2D [minX = -1680.0, minY=213.0, maxX=0.0, maxY=1263.0, width=1680.0, height=1050.0]
```

So the primary screen is listed first, with location (0,0), and the laptop screen is listed second, offset 1680 pixels to the left and 213 pixels lower than the primary screen.

In your code, the `x` and `y` coordinates of the stage are set to the `x` and `y` coordinates of the chosen (largest) screen in this coordinate system, so the top left of the stage will be at the top left of that screen. By setting the width and height of the stage to the width and height of the screen, the stage will exactly fill that screen (though you may lose some of the stage behind the system task bar or dock).

Here's a similar test example, which makes the window half the width and height of the screen, and centers it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScreenDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        VBox buttons = new VBox(5);
        buttons.setFillWidth(true);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        int index = 1 ;
        for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens()) {
            System.out.println(screen.getBounds());
            Button button = new Button("Screen "+index);
            button.setOnAction(e -> centerInScreen(stage, screen));
            button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            buttons.getChildren().add(button);
            index++;
        }
        HBox root = new HBox(buttons);
        root.setFillHeight(true);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        centerInScreen(stage, Screen.getPrimary());
        stage.show();
    }

    private void centerInScreen(Stage stage, Screen screen) {
        // make window half screen size and center in screen:
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getBounds();
        double x = screenBounds.getMinX();
        double y = screenBounds.getMinY();
        double w = screenBounds.getWidth();
        double h = screenBounds.getHeight();
        stage.setX(x + w/4);
        stage.setY(y + h/4);
        stage.setWidth(w/2);
        stage.setHeight(h/2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here's a similar example which centers a stage in every screen:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScreenDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        int index = 1 ;
        for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens()) {
            if (screen != Screen.getPrimary()) {
                Label label = new Label("Window in screen "+index);
                BorderPane root = new BorderPane(label);
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                Stage window = new Stage();
                window.setScene(scene);
                centerInScreen(window, screen);
                window.show();
            }
            index++;
        }
        Label label = new Label("Window in primary screen");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        centerInScreen(stage, Screen.getPrimary());
        stage.show();
    }

    private void centerInScreen(Stage stage, Screen screen) {
        // make window half screen size and center in screen:
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getBounds();
        double x = screenBounds.getMinX();
        double y = screenBounds.getMinY();
        double w = screenBounds.getWidth();
        double h = screenBounds.getHeight();
        stage.setX(x + w/4);
        stage.setY(y + h/4);
        stage.setWidth(w/2);
        stage.setHeight(h/2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a `Window` convenience method to [`centerOnScreen`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#centerOnScreen()).